# Remove quick create aka new Contact/Account/Whatever from all lookups in lightning experience

Tags: lookup, lightning-experience

I have disabled 'Show Quick Create' option from User Interface settings.
It's working fine in Classic and not showing new button in lookup search window.
However, I am unable to disable it in lightning. I have browsed through a lot of Salesforce Documentation and I am unable to disable it. 
Is it a limitation of Lightning Experience?

[image: Disable new contact lookup lightning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read and researched it doesn't seem possible to shut them off with the button, but you can still shut them off, you just need to go to three different places.

Lightning Quick Actions Locations

1. Global Actions : These can be deleted here: User Interface > Global Actions > Global Actions or they can be hidden from the UI here: User Interface > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts   
   If you delete an action that is in a layout, the UI breaks and none of the buttons are visible on the individual record page.
2. Object Actions:  These can be removed via Object Manager > Object > Page Layouts > Page Layout > Quick Actions.
3. Related Lists Actions:  You can edit the button available to the related lists (aka Contacts section under an Account’s details) by navigating to Object Manager > Object > Page Layouts > Page Layout > Quick Actions, if you click on the wrench next to the section in question, then click on the buttons sections header, from here you can show/hide buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove it is to create an aura component that imports a css static resource, and add it to the page. This will take effect only on that page of course.

static resource:

```
.createNew {
  display: none;
}
```

aura component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
  <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.cssStaticResource}" />
</aura:component>
```